# Android Alarm not triggering

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to trigger an alarm with android but it does not work. My code does not give a Toast or "ALARMOFF" message. I have this BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static void addAlarm(Context context){
        Log.i("infodb","ADDEDALARM");
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // For example
        Log.i("infodb","ALARMOFF");
        wl.release();
    }

}
```

In the manifest I have `<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />` as well as `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Alarms are trigged when switches are turned on in a ListView. The code for this is in the bindView method of an extended SimpleCursorAdapter class:

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        final long time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("time"));

        TextView time_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        if (time_text != null) {
            time_text.setText(date_format.format(new Date(time)));
        }

        TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        if (name_text != null) {
            name_text.setText(name);
        }

        // Do on/off button alarm code

        Switch onOff = (Switch)v.findViewById(R.id.alarm_switch);
        onOff.setChecked(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("onOff")) == 1);
        final Context contextl = context;
        final long id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        onOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                AlarmDatabase database = new AlarmDatabase(contextl);
                SQLiteDatabase write = database.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
                if (isChecked){
                    // Alarm has been turned on
                    values.put("onOff",1);
                    // Add system alarm
                    AlarmReceiver.addAlarm(contextl);
                }else{
                    // Alarm has been switched off
                    values.put("onOff",0);
                    // Remove system alarm

                }
                write.update(AlarmDatabase.ALARMS_TABLE, values, "_id = " + id, null);
                write.close();
                database.close();
            }

        });
    }
```

LogCat shows the following when a switch is turned on:

```
12-06 13:50:12.365: I/infodb(18968): ADDEDALARM
12-06 13:50:12.370: W/AlarmManager(2120): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-06 13:50:13.785: W/PowerManagerService(2120): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
12-06 13:50:13.785: I/PowerManagerService(2120): Ulight 0x7->0x3|0x0
12-06 13:50:13.785: D/lights(2120): button : 2 +
12-06 13:50:13.785: D/lights(2120): button : 2 -
12-06 13:50:13.785: D/PowerManagerService(2120): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
12-06 13:50:13.865: W/AlarmManager(2120): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-06 13:50:13.865: W/AlarmManager(2120): FACTORY_ON= 0
12-06 13:50:17.370: V/AlarmManager(2120): waitForAlarm result :1
12-06 13:50:17.375: V/AlarmManager(2120): trigger WAKEUP Alarm{41ec8190 type 0 XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX}
12-06 13:50:18.835: V/AlarmManager(2120): waitForAlarm result :1
12-06 13:50:18.870: V/AlarmManager(2120): trigger WAKEUP Alarm{41dc01e0 type 0 XXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX}
```

I've look in various places for a solution but I can only determine that I'm doing everything correctly but clearly I am not.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, you should use package name correctly, if you have different package ,

<receiver android:name="XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.AlarmReceiver" />

Comment: My goodness, I put the AlarmReceiver in a different package by accident! I didn't see that before... Let me test it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use package name correctly, if you have different package ,

receiver android:name="XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.AlarmReceiver" />

Comment: Yes, you are completely correct. :-) The solution was to simply move the receiver into the correct package. It was all a silly accident and I didn't think to look at the packages.

Comment: it is nice to hear that it fixed youe problem. I have done this accident too much before :):)